# How to create custom Take() in Linq (with LinqExtender 3)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Im building this custom provider for db2, and id like to know, if there´s anyway to build a custom "Take" method, cuz in db2, the "LIMIT" (or TOP) is built like this:

`select x from y FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY...-`

How can I do that?

Or, can I write this fetch, with linq?

Comment: This should not be hard what have you tried?

Comment: Please show some code.